# Cocos2d-JS how to integrate a custom Android plugin?

Tags: android, cocos2d-js

I want to integrate a custom Android plugin to my Cocos2d-JS app. I could not find any documentation on this. Any help is appreciated. I came across this link 
http://www.supersuraccoon-cocos2d.com/2014/03/02/a-simple-solution-on-implementing-bluetooth-multiplayer-with-cocos2d-html5-jsbinding-cocos2d-x-gamekit/

But its about iOS. Any help is appreciated!